# Git rebase with default parameters doesn't detect conflict. Why?

Tags: git

I have this scenario:

Simple C# project with some files: Fun1.cs, Fun2.cs, Fun3.cs. 
Files contains empty classes.

I have two branches:

- branchone where file Fun3.cs is deleted
- branchtwo where file Fun3.cs is modified.

I merge brachone into master and now i try on branchtwo to execute:
git rebase master

I was expecting to get confict - Fun3.cs is already deleted - but instead there is no conflict and changes from Fun3.cs are applied to Fun1.cs(!)

Git rebase with other options like:

```
git rebase -i master
git rebase master -m
git rebase master -s recursive
git rebase master -s recursive -X rename-threshold=100
git rebase master -s recursive -Xpatience
```

all detect confilct.

Console output:

```
/GitCondingDojo/Example/MyProject (branchtwo)
$ git rebase master -m
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): MyGitApp/Fun3.cs deleted in master and modified in HEAD~0. Version HEAD~0 of MyGitApp/Fun3.cs left in tree.

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".


/GitCondingDojo/Example/MyProject (branchtwo|REBASE-m 1/1)
$ git rebase --abort

/GitCondingDojo/Example/MyProject (branchtwo)
$ git rebase master -s recursive
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): MyGitApp/Fun3.cs deleted in master and modified in HEAD~0. Version HEAD~0 of MyGitApp/Fun3.cs left in tree.

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".


/GitCondingDojo/Example/MyProject (branchtwo|REBASE-m 1/1)
$ git rebase --abort

/GitCondingDojo/Example/MyProject (branchtwo)
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: added functionality to Fun3
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A       MyGitApp/Fun3.cs
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging MyGitApp/Fun1.cs
```

What is the rationale behind this behaviour? Is there a "safe" or "recommended" set of parameters for rebase?

Comment: FYI.. I was able to replicate your scenario: https://github.com/cyborgx37/sandbox/commits/branchtwo

Comment: Here's `branchtwo` before the rebase: https://github.com/cyborgx37/sandbox/tree/branchtwo-original

Answer (score 1):

This is rename detection detects false renames. Try adding `-Xno-renames` option to the rebase command

> Is there a "safe" or "recommended" set of parameters for rebase?

I'm afraid there is no universally matching set of optoins. The cases on "no conflict" side like your are more rare than on "conflict" side, so usually it is detected and then you have an options to retry with other options. In case like your it may go unnoticed so that you'd have to fix it later. Hopefully, the information is not lost and you could later to move it to right place.

Comment: With -Xnorenames it works correctly (conflict detected). I found it strange that git rebase master -s recursive also work (conflict detected). Recursive is supposed to be default behaviour param for rebase so I expected that it should fail and merge with wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a `git fetch origin` before `git rebase master`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Sounds like this is all happening locally. I don't see how a `fetch` would make any difference.

Comment: Yes. This is all happening locally.